# TypeError: Cannot read propety of undefined. GraphQL Mutation with Apollo Server and Sequelize

Tags: javascript, graphql, sequelize.js

this is my first time trying out GraphQl and i came across this error on playground:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'PaymentInfo' of undefined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createCreditCard"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'PaymentInfo' of undefined",
            "    at _callee3$ (/Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/src/resolvers/payment.js:18:23)",
            "    at tryCatch (/Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)",
            "    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:288:22)",
            "    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)",
            "    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/src/resolvers/payment.js:8:103)",
            "    at _next (/Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/src/resolvers/payment.js:10:194)",
            "    at /Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/src/resolvers/payment.js:10:364",
            "    at new Promise (<anonymous>)",
            "    at /Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/src/resolvers/payment.js:10:97",
            "    at createCreditCard (/Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/src/resolvers/payment.js:11:25)",
            "    at field.resolve (/Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/node_modules/graphql-extensions/src/index.ts:274:18)",
            "    at resolveFieldValueOrError (/Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:467:18)",
            "    at resolveField (/Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:434:16)",
            "    at /Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:244:18",
            "    at /Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/promiseReduce.js:23:10",
            "    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)",
            "    at promiseReduce (/Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/promiseReduce.js:20:17)",
            "    at executeFieldsSerially (/Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:241:37)",
            "    at executeOperation (/Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:219:55)",
            "    at executeImpl (/Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:104:14)",
            "    at Object.execute (/Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:64:35)",
            "    at /Users/milano/Documents/Projects/mtg-shop-v1/mtg-shop-server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts:464:30"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

All I wanted to do is to create on my db(I`m using postgres) a new "PaymentInfo" using the playground.

My mutation:

```
  mutation {
    createCreditCard(cvv: 165, cardNumber: 123654376, isValid: true) {
      id
    }
  }
```

my resolver:

```
    Mutation: {
        createCreditCard: async (parent, { me, models }) => {
            try {
                return await models.PaymentInfo.create({
                    paymentInfos,
                    userId: me.id,
                });
            } catch (error) {
                throw new Error(error);
            }
        },
```

My schema:

```
    createCreditCard(
      cardNumber: Int!
      cvv: Int!
      isValid: Boolean!
    ): PaymentInfo!
    deleteCreditCard(id: ID!): Boolean!
  }
```

What doesn't add up is that i can create anything using sequelize querys through code(https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html#querying) but when it comes to using mutations on playground i simply can't.

I'm sure that i'm doing something wrong on the mutation syntax on playground but i can't figure out what.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a problem with your resolver. Graphql resolvers are passed four arguments - `obj, args, context, info`. I am guessing that `{ me, models }` is an attempt to destructure your context, but there may be an issue because you are not accoutning for or accessing the intervening args object, which you will need to access the `createCreditCard` variables (in fact, not seeing where paymentInfos is defined). Perhaps try something like the following:

```
   Mutation: {
        createCreditCard: async (parent, args, { me, models }) => {
            try {
                const paymentInfos = { ...args };
                console.log(paymentInfos); // confirm you are passing object of correct shape to db
                return await models.PaymentInfo.create({
                    paymentInfos,
                    userId: me.id,
                });
            } catch (error) {
                throw new Error(error);
            }
        },
```